# Can 12 be placed in (2,4) of a grid having 1-25 such that rows and column add upto 65?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say one person was to arrange a 5x5 grid, of the natural numbers from 1 to 25, in such a manner that each of the rows and columns were to add up to 65. Then how probable would 12 be to be placed at 2nd row and 4th column?

My intention is to understand this problem not only with specifics but also in generalized scenario where the rows and columns may or may not be equal in number and instead of the first few numbers we take some other set of numbers which may or may not be sequential.

Comment: To clarify, the grid contains all natural numbers from 1 to 25? What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What progress have you made?

Comment: In order to ask how probable something is, you need to specify the manner it was randomly chosen. What is the set of all possible grids you are choosing from, exactly?

Comment: @JeanMarie 25*26/2 is equal to 4 * 65, precisely.

Comment: @MikeEarnest the objective is to place natural numbers 1 to 25 on a 5 by 5 grid and the criteria is that rows and columns must add up to 65.

Comment: I am thinking of getting subsets of a set containing natural numbers till 25 such that the sum of the elements is equal to 65 and then finding collections of 5 of them such that they do not have any intersection and their union is the parent set. I found generating subsets from the method shown in 3b1b video on olympiad level counting and the union of sets to form parent set from one of the questions in here.

Comment: @Mike Earnest My bad. Deleted.

Comment: @AdityaGupta I recommend editting your comment into your post. Many readers will skip a post if they don't see what effort the poster has made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from a random grid arrangement that satisfies the conditions that each row and column sum up to $65$. Now swap the first and second rows. The row sums are still $65$, and within each column, we have just swapped the first and second elements, so the column sums are also $65$. That means it's still a valid grid. Generalizing, one can swap any two rows or columns and maintain the validity of the condition.

Suppose $12$ is currently in row $i$ and column $j$. If we want it to be in the 2nd row and 4th column, then just swap rows $i$ and $2$, then columns $j$ and $4$.But notice there was nothing about this process that could only work for the 2nd row and 4th column. This means that we can move $12$ to any position we want simply by swapping rows and columns.

Visually, the outer cells seems different from the inner. But based on the mathematical conditions we have, there's no real distinction. So by symmetry, it's as likely (or 'easy') to move $12$ to $(2,4)$ as to any other position. Meaning that all positions are equally likely for $12$. So probability is $\frac{1}{25}$ for any specific position.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a grid of numbers where the rows and columns all add up to the same number, then you can generate other grids with that same property by permuting the rows or permuting the columns.

If, additionally, the grid contains each whole number 1-25 exactly once, then you are guaranteed there is a 12 somewhere, say at (r,c). We can therefore associate every such solution with a solution where the 12 is at (2,4) by first swapping rows r and 2 (possibly changing nothing if r=2 already) and then swapping columns c and 4 (possibly changing nothing). Since these operations can be undone, this means there are exactly 25 general solutions associated with each "12 at (2,4)" solution.

So if you choose uniformly from among solutions, and there are any solutions, then there's a 1/25 chance that 12 is at (2,4).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for "magic squares."  Here is an example:

$\begin {array}
17&24&1&8&15\\
23&5&7&14&16\\
4&6&13&20&22\\
10&12&19&21&3\\
11&18&25&2&9
\end{array}$

This also has the characteristic that the sum across the diagonals is also 65.

The next thing I see is that any reflection or rotation of a magic square is a magic square.

If we don't require the diagonals to sum to 65, too, then any swap of rows or columns maintains the magic square nature.

That means that there is an equal likelihood that the 12 be at any coordinate of the grid.